# Is this theorem true?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, functional-equations, real-numbers

If $f(x)+f(y)=f(x+y)$, then:

$f(x)=a x$

where $a$ is a constant.

Is the above statement true? Is there a way of proving it?

The application of this theorem is in the last part of **page 52 *(second page of the chapter)***

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you mind posting the complete question?

Comment: no, it is not true in general

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation

Comment: Aren't there some other conditions, say something about continuity...?

Comment: Sorry.. I don't have a back in real analysis. I came across an application of this theorem in a phycis book. Take a look at my edited question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we are considering functions $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, this is known as [Cauchy's functional equation.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation)

To summarize the Wikipedia article, if you also require $f$ to satisy any of the below conditions, then $f(x) = ax$ is the only family of solutions:

- $f$ is continuous at at least one point
- $f$ is monotonic on any interval
- $f$ is bounded on any interval
- $f$ is Lebesgue measurable

**As this is being used for an application, I would guess that it is being assumed $f$ is continuous at at least one point, implying that $f(x) = ax$.**

The wikipedia article also mentions that any other solutins are highly pathological; if you were to graph them, the graph would look like you are just shading the paper. More formally, if you take a disk of any size anywhere on the paper, that disk will contain a point $(x, f(x))$ of the function.

Let me know if anything needs clarification.

---

**EDIT:**

1) I haven't looked at all the proofs, but [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/423492/overview-of-basic-facts-about-cauchy-functional-equation) seems to be a great resource.

2) There are many inintuitive things in mathematics as I'm sure there are in physics :). One example of a function which is discontinous everywhere is

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}0, \text{ if x is irrational} \\1, \text{ if x is rational}\end{cases}$$

If you were to draw this function it would look like two continous horizontal lines; but of course they're riddled with infinitesimal holes.

To prove this function is discontinous at every point, you have to prove that $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) \not = f(a)$ for any $a$.

Bounded just means that the function is cut off height-wise; for example $\sin x$ is bounded because it doesn't go higher/lower than $\pm1$, which $x^2$ and $x^3$ are not bounded.

Lebesgue measurable is a bit more complicated; the Lebesgue measure, $m$, of a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is its length. For example the measure of $[3, 5]$ is $2$; the measure of a single point is $0$. But stranger things happen too; it turns out that the measure of $\mathbb{Q}$, the set of all the rational numbers on the number line, is also $0$.

Now the "$f$ is Lebesgue measurable" condition is very very weak; to find a function which is not Lebesgue measurable, it requires you to find a set which is not Lebesgue measuable, which means a set with no length. For a long time mathematicians thought such a set is impossible, until a guy named Vitali came up with his [Vitali set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set).

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer...  (1) Can you please give a reference to a proof of this theorem if it is not that much intricate for a physics graduate student.  (2) How can a function be discontinuous at every point. It seems impossible for me to imagine such a function.

Comment: I haven't yet studied bounded and Lebesgue measurable functions in my course.

Comment: I have read the Wikipedia article and now I understand how a function can be discontinuous at every point. Can you show me in my problem (page 52) that the function under consideration is not discontinuous at every point.

Comment: @Joe I've edited the question with info about your comments. I don't know physics, so I think you may have more luck with your quetion about page $52$ on physics stackexchange or electrical engineering stackexchange https://physics.stackexchange.com/ https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Just one more thing to clarify. Can you explain a bit about how a function cannot be monotonic on any interval?

Comment: Wikipedia is too intricate for me....

Answer (score 5):

Hard to say anything unless you state the sets the function is defined on.